# Can we have row addition to a grid in a web application using Microsoft technology

Tags: .net, silverlight, gridview, dynamic-data

The GridView in ASP.NET does not allow directly adding a row to the grid. For editing a row, the user has to click the 'Edit' button , make changes , then click 'Update'. To overcome this people use third party Grid from Telerik and others. Is there any way around this issue if we use Silverlight based Grids ? Does 'Dynamic Data Framework' or other frameworks from Microsoft help us overcome this issue ?

Thanks and regards,
Chak.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably be better off using [GridView combined with jQuery](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1532-gridview-and-jquery-asp-net-tutorial.aspx) instead of having a Silverlight island in your page.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the row to the datasource and rebind or use a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) control.